# Trekking tips to Langtang

Tags: national-parks, trekking, nepal

I'm thinking of trekking toward [Langtang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langtang_National_Park), Nepal.  As i don't have much knowledge of the really place and about trekking. I with my team have planned to move at the end of march. so any one who has been there or have trek on such location may provide me ideas on the trekking tips.

Comment: Hi devilsmind. It seems that you are asking a forum-style question whereas Stack Exchange is specifically designed for specific questions with specific answers by experts. Please read our [FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq) and see if you can edit this question to ask something specific. Otherwise I can recommend Lonely Planet Thorn Tree as a very good travel forum.

Comment: If you do edit it, feel free to flag it for the moderators and we can consider reopening it!